# Differences between finite supremum and bounded supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Are there any differences between,
$$\sup_{n\geq 1} a_n<+\infty$$
and
$$\sup_{n\geq 1} a_n \leq M \text{ for some } M\geq 0 \text{ independent of } n$$
here $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is some given positive sequence.

Thank you very much if you could provide a detailed clarification!

Comment: It's kind of meaningless to say that $M$ is independent of $n$, because $\sup_{n\geq 1} a_n$ is independent of $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no differences. Both expressions mean:

the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded from above.